# How to find Maximum element in List with maybe output

Tags: haskell, option-type

This code works

```
max_elem :: (Ord a) => [a] -> a 
max_elem [x] = x 
max_elem [] = error "No elements" 
max_elem (x:xs)  
    |x > max_elem xs = x 
    |otherwise = max_elem xs
```

I want to have it so it returns Nothing if their are no elements and Just x for the maximum element
I tried the following

```
max_elem :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Maybe a 
max_elem [x] = Just x 
max_elem [] = Nothing
max_elem (x:xs) 
    |x >  max_elem xs = Just x
    |otherwise = max_elem xs
```

I got the following error. Recommendations to fix this please.

```
 • Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Maybe a’
      ‘a’ is a rigid type variable bound by
        the type signature for:
          max_elem :: forall a. Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
        at <interactive>:208:13
    • In the second argument of ‘(>)’, namely ‘max_elem xs’
      In the expression: x > max_elem xs
      In a stmt of a pattern guard for
                     an equation for ‘max_elem’:
        x > max_elem xs
    • Relevant bindings include
        xs :: [a] (bound at <interactive>:211:13)
        x :: a (bound at <interactive>:211:11)
        max_elem :: [a] -> Maybe a (bound at <interactive>:209:1)
```

Comment: " Couldn't match expected type ‘a’ with actual type ‘Maybe a’", "In the second argument of ‘(>)’, namely ‘max_elem xs’". seems clear to me

Comment: You could try `import Data.List (findIndex)` and `findIndex (== maximum x) x`, but it would be better to find your error.

Comment: I really prefer to divide specific operations into specific functions. There is the calculation and there is the error checking and input validation. Each, it seems to me, in a separate function is cleaner.

Answer (score 2):

The error message was clear enough to solve your problem.

```
|x >  max_elem xs = Just x
```

The problem is that you compare `x` which is `a` with `max_elem` which is `Maybe a`. That's why you got such error message. You can solve the problem with this code below.

```
max_elem :: (Ord a) => [a] -> Maybe a 
max_elem []     = Nothing
max_elem (x:xs) = case (max_elem xs) of
  Nothing -> Just x
  Just y  -> if x > y then Just x else Just y
```

Comment: I'd use `else Just y`, otherwise we recompute the maximum, causing an exponential blow up!

Comment: @chi Thanks! Edited.

Comment: "max_elem [x]    = Just x" could be skipped

Comment: @max630 Thanks! Edited.

Answer (score 2):

You get your error because of this line: `x >  max_elem xs`. `max_elem xs` has type `Maybe a` where `a` is an element of a list. It has type `a`. You can't compare values of different types. `a` and `Maybe a` are different types. See Haskell equality table:

- https://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/quchen/articles/blob/master/haskell-equality-table.html

Replace `==` operator with `>` and you will get the same table.

You can solve problem in your code by replacing `x >  max_elem xs` with `Just x > max_elem xs`. Does it make sense to you?

As you can see, `Maybe a` data type has `Ord a => Ord (Maybe a)` instance which is actually really handy! So you can implement your function in even more concise way to utilize this `Ord` instance:

```
max_elem :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a 
max_elem = foldr max Nothing . map Just
```

Though, this probably won't be the most efficient solution if you care about performance.

Comment: `fmap maximum (if null x then Nothing else Just x)` is probably simpler. No need to wrap each element of the list in `Just`, just a non-empty list itself.

Comment: Well, in real world I wouldn't use `maximum` function for list at first place anyways. The cost of wrapping every element into `Maybe` is nothing compared to inefficiency of  `maximum` function, which most likely contains space leaks.

Comment: `maximum` isn't much more than a wrapper around `foldMap` using a `Max` monoid; it's not that much different than what you wrote above.

Comment: Yeah, as as I said in my anwer, my implementation also not perfect. It has the same problem. But I guess it's okay for Haskell beginner not to dive into such things for now.

Comment: Sorry, I meant to come back and note the my suggestion could also be simplified to `if null x then Nothing else maximum x`, since `maximum` basically just assumes that the fold won't return `Nothing` (it's literally a composition of `fromJust` and `foldr`.)

Comment: @chepner This solution is much nicer, you're right :)

Answer (score 1):

We can generalize this task and work with all `Foldable`s. Here we thus use the [**`foldr :: Foldable t => (a -> b -> b) -> b -> t a -> b`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.11.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:foldr) function that folds a certain `Foldable` structure. We can do this with the function `max . Just`, and as initial element `Nothing`:

```
max_elem :: (Ord a, Foldable f) => f a -> Maybe a 
max_elem = foldr (max . Just) Nothing
```

Note that this works since Haskell defines `Maybe a` to be an instance of `Ord`, given `a` is an instance of `Ord`, and it implements it in a way that `Nothing` is smaller than any `Just` element.

This makes the above definition perhaps a bit "unsafe" (in the sense that we here rely on the fact that from the moment we have a `Just x`, the `max` will select such `Just x` over a `Nothing`). When we would use `min`, this would not work (not without using some tricks).

We can also use pattern guards and thus solve the case where the list is empty in a different way, like:

```
max_elem :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a 
max_elem [] = Nothing
max_elem l = Just (maximum l)
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is `x > max_elem xs`; `max_elem xs` is `Maybe a`, not `a`, meaning that it might return `Nothing`.   However, you do know that it will only return `Nothing` if `xs` is empty, but you know `xs` won't be empty because you matched the case where it would `using [x]`.  You can take advantage of this fact by writing a "non-empty" maximum:

```
max_elem_ne :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> a
max_elem_ne m []     = m
max_elem_ne m (x:xs)
  | m > x     = max_elem m xs
  | otherwise = max_elem x xs
```

Or, alternatively, using `max`:

```
max_elem_ne :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> a
max_elem_ne m []     = m
max_elem_ne m (x:xs) = max_elem (max m x) xs
```

You can think of the first argument as the maximum value seen "so far", and the second list argument as the list of other candidates.

In this last form, you might have noticed that `max_elem_ne` is actually a just left fold, so you could even just write:

```
max_elem_ne :: Ord a => a -> [a] -> a
max_elem_ne = foldl' max
```

Now, with `max_elem_ne`, you can write your original `max_elem`:

Then you can write:

```
max_elem :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
max_elem []     = Nothing
max_elem (x:xs) = Just (max_elem_ne x xs)
```

So you don't have to do any extraneous checks (like you would if you redundantly pattern matched on results), and the whole thing is type-safe.

You can also use the `uncons :: [a] -> Maybe (a,[a])` utility function with `fmap` and `uncurry` to write:

```
max_elem :: Ord a => [a] -> Maybe a
max_elem = fmap (uncurry max_elem_ne) . uncons
```